# dynamically update device info react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-device-info to get DeviceLocale or DeviceCountry. But is there a way that I can update Device-info with out restarting the app. 
For Example, on device settings If my language is set to "English(US)", Device-info cam detect that but if I change the settings to "English(CA)",Device-Info is not able to capture that until I restart the app.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How are you changing the settings of the language?

If it's built in...you can do something like setting the language as a state of the component and once call the function to change the language settings, you can setState and it'll update the component with the new value.

If you're talking about hopping out of the app and manually changing the language settings then maybe setting creating a setInterval to check the device-info will work.

Comment: Hi Matt, 

I am changing the language manually. SetInterval is not an user action so it will keep on repeating. 

I am looking for a way to trigger the below code on user interface(for example while navigating).So, it happens only once. 

let DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
  let locale = DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're defining the reference to `DeviceInfo` outside of the component's class definition, you could try moving it inside like this.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  checkDeviceInfo() {
    let DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
    let locale = DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale();
    // do something with locale
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.checkDeviceInfo.bind(this)}>
        <Text>Touch Here</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

You could put this in your component so that it's called whenever you want to check for `DeviceInfo` changes.

Comment: DeviceInfo wont be updated until we restart the app. I want to update that by user interaction.

Comment: You could.. that's what my code is doing.. just call `someFuncToCheckDeviceInfo` during a user interaction.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few steps you can consider:

1. **Use a Listener for Locale Changes (Android):**
   On Android, you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for changes to the locale settings. When a change is detected, you can update the information in your app. Note that this might require additional permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml.

   ```java
   // In your RNDeviceInfoModule.java
   private BroadcastReceiver localeChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           // Locale has changed, update your information
           updateDeviceInfo();
       }
   };

   @ReactMethod
   public void startListeningForLocaleChanges() {
       IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED);
       getReactApplicationContext().registerReceiver(localeChangeReceiver, intentFilter);
   }

   @ReactMethod
   public void stopListeningForLocaleChanges() {
       getReactApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(localeChangeReceiver);
   }

   private void updateDeviceInfo() {
       // Update DeviceLocale and DeviceCountry here
   }
   ```

   You would need to call `startListeningForLocaleChanges` when your component mounts and `stopListeningForLocaleChanges` when it unmounts.
2. **Use a Similar Mechanism on iOS:**
   On iOS, you might need to implement a similar mechanism using NotificationCenter to listen for locale changes.

   ```objectivec
   // In your RNDeviceInfoModule.m
   - (void)localeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
       // Locale has changed, update your information
       [self updateDeviceInfo];
   }

   - (void)startListeningForLocaleChanges {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                selector:@selector(localeChanged:)
                                                    name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:nil];
   }

   - (void)stopListeningForLocaleChanges {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                       name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification
                                                     object:nil];
   }

   - (void)updateDeviceInfo {
       // Update DeviceLocale and DeviceCountry here
   }
   ```

   Similarly, call `startListeningForLocaleChanges` when your component mounts and `stopListeningForLocaleChanges` when it unmounts.

Remember to handle cleanup appropriately, especially unregistering the listeners when they are no longer needed to avoid potential memory leaks.

Please note that while these solutions might work for locale changes, capturing changes in other settings, such as the time zone, might require a different approach. Always consider the specific needs and limitations of your app when implementing dynamic updates.

Comment: Posting AI-generated answers is [forbidden on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).